# How can I use Mockito for testing database calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

So Im new to junit and mockito. I decided that I wanted to try building a spring boot project that actually had some testing done in it. Here is what I have so far.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AccountServiceTest {

    private AccountService accountService;

    @Mock
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void initServices(){
        this.accountService = new AccountService(accountRepository);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get Account by Name 'Foo'")
    void getAccountByName() {
        assertNotNull(accountService);

        //Create mocks
        Account expected = new Account("2","Foo", "IT");
        when(accountRepository.findByName("Foo")).thenReturn(Optional.of(expected));

        Account actual = accountService.getAccountByName("Foo");
        assertEquals(expected.getId(), actual.getId(), "Error, actual doesnt match expected");
    }
}
```

Now this test passes but to my understanding I realised that I'm just feeding in the values that I want to appear using that "when" function call. What is the purpose of mocking this function when I don't know if the actual service will behave this way? Basically is my understanding right that I'm feeding the values that I want to appear or is the service actually being called and making the query to my database? Also if it is this case that im feeding it those values then what is the point in testing this way?

Answer (score 0):

The point of testing this way is to make sure your AccountService work correctly, provided, that AccountRepository works correctly

You should not use Mockito to test database interaction. Use embedded database like h2 for that